# AmCharts - empty gap in a Column graph if valueField doesn't exist in dataProvider

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to create a chart using AmCharts v3 library.
But, I am getting a empty gap between two columns if another valueField doesn't exist in dataProvider.

Please take a look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/05znyqfd/10/

The `category 2` graph shows gap between `value1` and `value3` columns.

How can I avoid this issue.

Comment: There's no way to "collapse" the columns with values over the space reserved for the no-value column, I'm afraid. I'm not aware for any workarounds either. Will take it up with development if this feature can be implemented. (I work for amCharts)

Comment: @martynasma Thanks! I'm surprised no one faced this issue before.

Comment: @anilmwr have you found any way of doing this? I am also having same problem but haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: @anilmwr have you found any way of doing this? I am also having same problem but haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: @arj I added -1 value in data itself for categories which didn't have valueField defined, its just to indicate that those values are not defined

Comment: @anilmwr as per my understanding you mean that you added "value2": -1  ( {"category": "category 2", "value1": 4, "value2": "-1", "value3": 6}) where value2 was not defined in your jsfiddle example. But this just displays the inverted bar for -1 below the x-axis

Comment: @arj Yes, it displays the bar below x-axis. In my case, all data values are supposed to be positive or 0, never negative. Bars with -1 value below x-axis is just an indicator to the viewer that its not valid. I also added a note to the chart as a disclaimer to point it out.

Comment: @anilmwr thank you. I was actually trying to use "Clustered multi-segment stacked column chart with sub-categories" by amcharts but due to gaps in my data it wasn't useful. Unfortunately, I can't use the -1 solution based on my dataset. Finally I have found an alternative solution by amcharts "Display data break down on different chart when clicked on a column" which displays the sub-categories of any category in separate chart